# sql select sum count variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select tableA, count(id) group by acc_id and SUM(6 - total).

```
TableA
ID | acc_id | user_id
1  |  2     |   20
2  |  2     |   21
3  |  3     |   22
4  |  3     |   10
```

Expecty Result:

```
 total: 8
```

I tried:

```
select 6-count(id) as total
from tableA 
group by acc_id 
having total < 6 AND total <> 0
```

My output:

```
total: 4, total: 4
```

I just need to sum it in the end. How can I do it?

Comment: checkout `rollup` function in mysql along with `group by`

Comment: What is `6-count(id)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I think he counts the number of ids and then calculates six minus that number. So `6 - COUNT(id)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh yea ... DUH Silly me

Comment: Yes I need to sub this number

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty I tried rollup and I coulnd do ):

Comment: so what do you want if some `acc_id` group has more count(id)>6? why do you apply `HAVING`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM (
    SELECT 6-count(id) AS total
    FROM tableA 
    GROUP BY acc_id
) sub
GROUP BY total
HAVING total < 6 AND total <> 0
```

Comment: it didnt work, I got this: Unknown column 'total' in 'having clause'

Comment: The `HAVING` clause should be inside the subquery.

Comment: Or you can change it to `WHERE`.

Comment: Either of @Barmars options or my edited answer should work

Comment: It is working, but it total equals zero, it does count as plus 6

Comment: Try my edited answer, it will group it first then use the having statement

Comment: It didnt work, I got this: [{"sum(total)":"4"},{"sum(total)":"4"}]

Comment: I think that I just need to put a IF inside the query, like IF(total = 0, 6)

Answer (score 0):

I did it, I got code from @Samuel O'Connor and edit it:

```
 select sum(if(total = 0,6,total)) as total_sum
    from(
      select
          6-count(id) as total 
            from tableA 
            group by acc_id) sub
            where total < 6
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not clear.

But here my attempt to get your expected 8

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4b76/3

```
SELECT SUM(t.total)
FROM (
SELECT 6-COUNT(id) as total
FROM TableA
GROUP BY acc_id) t
```